# multidimensional arrays and methods

Tags: java, methods, multidimensional-array

I have a homework assignment and the program generates a random number of students taking a random number of tests. The user must enter the students names and test scores. Once that is done the program will print on the screen : STUDENT REPORT Scores for Fred:
    Test #1: 78
    Test #2: 80
    Average for Fred: 79.0
Scores for Sue:
    Test #1: 91
    Test #2: 94
    Average for Sue: 92.5

... and so on depending on what number of students and tests you get.

I get everything right up until the average part how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
   public static void populateNames(String[] names)
   {
     for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++)
     {
       out.print("Enter student " + (i+1) + " name: ");
       names[i] = keyboard.next();
     }
   } 

  // Code your 3 methods below...
 //Ask the user for the student name as well as the test scores
   public static void populateTestScores(String[] names, int[][] scores)
   {
     out.println();
     for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
     {
        out.println();
        out.println("Entering scores for: " + names[i]);

        for(int s=0; s<scores[0].length; s++)
        {
            out.print("Enter score for test #" + (s+1) + ": ");
            scores[i][s] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
    out.println();
}

  //Print each studdent test scores and ther average
  public static void printStudentReport(String[] names, int[][] scores)
  {
    out.println("STUDENT REPORT");
    for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
    {
        out.print("Scores for " + names[i] + ": ");
        out.println();

        for(int s=0; s<scores[0].length; s++)
        {
            out.println("Test #" + (s + 1) +  ": " + scores[i][s]);
        }
        out.println();
    int s=0;
    if(s<scores[0].length)
    {
        s++;
        double sum = 0;
        sum += scores[i][s];
        double average = sum / scores[0].length;
        out.println("Average for " + names[i] + ": " + average);
        out.println();
    }
    }
    out.println();
  }
```

Comment: What does it do that is not as wanted and what exactly do you want it to do? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry. it does not give me the correct average and it also prints STUDENT REPORT Scores for fred: Test 1: 89 average 43 test 2: average 32 Scores for sue: Test 1: 90 average 40 test 2: 90 average 50 and so on it prints the average with every test score. so it prints the average at every line after STUDENT REPORT and I just want it to print at the very last line before this loop is over - for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)

Comment: I just corrected my code. The average keeps coming back incorrect though so I don't know if its something with my calculations or something else please help. I need to get this done within 2 days

Comment: The question is not clear. Is the expected output really one long line of text? Please **edit the question** to clearly show the expected output and also to show the actual output. You are asking people here for help with your problem, please make it easy for us to understand what you want without us doing lots of work. If your question really is urgent then make it easy for us to understand quickly.

Comment: Add your output. Not clear what you are expecting for output.

Comment: For an average you need first to fetch the sum. Think how you would get a sum of an array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the way you're computing `sum` in `printStudentReport`: it only contains the second element in the list of scores because you're creating and adding to `sum` after the `for` loop (instead of creating before the loop and adding in it).

I'd rearrange that method to (reformatted for compactness):

```
// Print each studdent test scores and ther average
public static void printStudentReport(String[] names, int[][] scores) {
    out.println("STUDENT REPORT");
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        out.print("Scores for " + names[i] + ": ");
        out.println();

        double sum = 0;
        for (int s = 0; s < scores[0].length; s++) {
            out.println("Test #" + (s + 1) + ": " + scores[i][s]);
            sum += scores[i][s];
        }
        out.println();
        if (0 < scores[0].length) {
            double average = sum / scores[0].length;
            out.println("Average for " + names[i] + ": " + average);
            out.println();
        }
    }
    out.println();
}
```